# can I call base class method in my setup function

Tags: python

I am writing python script for the first time
Here is a basic question

```
class TestLolSupv(TestSetTxFreqPL4App,TestCaseAppForceReset):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        super().test_TX_SET_FREQ_PL4P2_A001()
```

Can I call base class method directly in this way in my setUp function?
Also if I am inheriting more than one base class , and super.setup() executes which both ? if so which one first ?

Comment: `super()` makes sense if you're overriding the method and want to call the parent's implementation, so calling `super().setUp()` from within `setUp()` makes sense. It makes little sense to use `super()` for `test_...` as well, that should probably just be `self.test_...()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, doing `super().setUp()` is the right way of calling the parent method class.

Now, regarding the multiple inheritance and the method calling. Python will actually call only the method of one class. When you do multiple inheritance, Python will create a 'Multiple-Resolution Order', that is the order in which python check the parent class for the method. Once it found the method in a parent it will  stop looking for the method (this normally happens, because the inheritance hierarchy may be big).

In your example, you resolution order would be:

```py
[<class '__main__.TestLolSupv'>, <class '__main__.TestSetTxFreqPL4App'>, <class '__main__.TestCaseAppForceReset'>, <class 'object'>]
```

You can check it by running `TestLolSupv.mro()`.

If you want to have control of the order the objects are being called, I would suggest using delegation instead. And also, if you are using inheritance to have access to parent class method, delegation would be better. Normally, inheritance is worth when the parent class calls a child class method, because this means you are building an abstraction.

Here is some [info](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/super-multiple-inheritance-diamond-problem) about multiple inheritance in python.

Answer (score 1):

`super.setup()` will search for `setup` method in all parent classes, starting from left to right, till it finds it and executes the first found method.

for example

```
class A(object):
  def setup(self):
    print("A")

class B(object):
  def setup(self):
    print("B")

class C(A, B):
  def setup(self):
    super().setup()

c = C()
c.setup()
```

will print the answer as "A".

if the parent classes have inherited from other classes, then they will be searched in that order.

example

```
class A(object):
  def setup(self):
    pass

class B(object):
  def setup(self):
    pass

class C(A):
  pass

class D(B):
  pass

class E(C, D):
  def setup(self):
    super().setup()

class F(D, C):
  def setup(self):
    super().setup()
```

now for E the setup in A will be executed, and for F setup in B will be executed.